# Building two applications into one

Tags: javascript, java, gradle, war

So I've two separate applications - one is REST Api written in java which is exported as a war. The other is a REACT javascript application which is rendered in a folder with 1 HTML, 1 CSS and 1 JS file.
Now my organization wants me to package the two applications in gradle and offer 1 single war for deployment.
Personally I think it's a terrible idea, but well, can't always choose.
My question is, can that even be done, if yes how can I do it. Important to note that it has to be a gradle build.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you should be able to package assets into your .war and have Tomcat (or whatever) serve them alongside your actual assets.

You should be able to place them alongside the WEB-INF folder at the same level. The container will serve them directly.

You probably want a build step that runs whatever JS things needs to run (minification, etc). Another build step could take the output of that and dump it into war.

Comment: Transpiling and minification of the front-end is already done. It's now a folder with only three files, as I've metioned. How do I write a gradle script that takes my REST Api war with this folder and produce an deployable war.

Comment: You should be able to simple dump the files to the directory above WEB-INF right before that WAR is generated. See the "Customizing" section of https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html